# How can I extract website names from irregularly named strings?

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I have a column that looks like:

```
this contains no website
this is a web site.io
another websi te.co
```

I want to create a column that looks like:

```
NULL
site
te
```

So in the case of no period, it should return NULL, but if there is a period it should return the thing between the period and the previous space.

Comment: Please share some codes.

Comment: @revo I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Some codes that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookahead like this:

```
\S+(?=\.\S+)
```

The first `\S+` is what you want and the lookahead `(?=\.\S+)` is the suffix (e.g `.com`, `.org`, `.net`, etc.).

Comment: Well played... I'd add just a little more stringency so it doesn't look at everything with a period in front of it

Comment: @SteveKline Yes, it looks at everything that precedes a dot, but it doesn't match all of them. For example, the match will fail on this: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultrices.`

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
\b(\w+)\.(?:io|co)\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gA1tK4/1).